# How to rotate javascript highchart line graph -90 degree without affecting the data values

Tags: highcharts

I have a popup container with a -90 degree rotate highchart line-chart. The graph is rotated. but the data values are not rotated and all the data are displayed at the bottom of the graph.

Highchart line graph with -90 degrees rotation
[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce it somehow in online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel. I have reproduced the error in JSFiddle. Please have a look. 

https://jsfiddle.net/gnanesdct/gjyqma7c/1/

Thanks

Comment: So you can see the JSFiddle example when we rotate the graph -90 degrees, and mouse over the graph data, the values on the graph is not plotting correctly on the corresponding position. This is the issue I am facing in my Project

Answer (score 0):

Set `chart.inverted = true`. It is the only way to rotate a chart correctly.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    inverted: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      fillOpacity: 0.1
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sb0L7vxu/